# How can I align the ActionMode done button on the right of the ActionBar instead of the left?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

As the title stands, is there a way to align the `ActionMode` **Done Button** on the right instead of the left? Or Should I hide it and add a menu button and manage its `onClick`?

Comment: What is the problem with leaving it on the left (or, more accurately, leaving it on the "start" side, depending on LTR/RTL languages)?

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your comment. It is not a problem.  I Just want to understand if it can be done

Comment: @Blackbelt I think it is possible, since the action mode view has an id "action_mode_bar" (or something like that), so you can find it and investigate its children.

Comment: @androiddeveloper thanks for your input, but the question is kind of old and I am not working on the project anymore. if you could provide an answer with a test case, I'll gladly accept it

Comment: @Blackbelt Sure. but it's quite short...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after you call "startActionMode" , you can find the view of the actionMode, and set its layout direction (or investigate it and then do what you wish) :

```
// <= call "startActionMode" here
final View actionModeView = findViewById(R.id.action_mode_bar);
if (actionModeView != null)
   actionModeView.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
```

I know that it works at least for Toolbar (when being set as an actionBar), using the support library.